# makeUntitledDocumentOfType:error: のTypeに指定する内容を教えて下さい

Tags: objective-c, macos

OS X / Objective-Cでコードを書いていますが、`NSDocument`のサブクラスドキュメントをインスタンスを取得しつつ作成するために、`makeUntitledDocumentOfType:error:`を使おうとしていますが、第一引数のdocumentTypeに何を指定すれば良いのかお教え下さい。

```
HogeDocument *unusedDocument = nil;
for (NSDocument *document in documents) {
    if (document.isDocumentEdited == NO) {
        unusedDocument = (HogeDocument *)document;
        break;
    }// end if found unused document
}// end foreach opened document / window
if (unusedDocument == nil) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDocumentController *dc = [NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController];
    NicoLiveDocument *document = (HogeDocument *)[dc makeUntitledDocumentOfType:@"ここに何を指定すれば良いのか" error:&error];
```

補足、`info.plist`には以下のように書いていて、第一引数は
https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsdocumentcontroller/1514963-makeuntitleddocumentoftype?language=objc
https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsdocumentcontroller/1514947-documentclassfortype?language=objc
を読んで、`CFBundleTypeName`のValue、`HogeDocumentLog`を指定していますが、実行しても戻り値はnil, errorには code -256が帰ってきて新規ウィンドウが作成されません。

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>.clog</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>application/xml</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>HogeDocumentLog</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>HogeDocumentLog</string>
        </array>
        <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
        <string>HogeDocument</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document-based applicationを作成すると、次のようなエントリーがInfo.plistにできるのはご存知かと思います。

[image: Info.plist]

**Document Type Name**(またはCFBundleTypeName)に入力されている内容が、`documentType`に指定すべき文字列になります。デフォルトでは`DocumentType`と言うズバリすぎて逆にわかりにくい内容になっていますが、適切な内容に書き換えた上でお試しください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ドキュメントは出来るようになりましたが、新規ウィンドウが開きません。

Comment: `makeUntitledDocumentOfType:error:`は指定したdocumentTypeのインスタンスを生成するだけで、UI要素は含まれていません。`openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:error:`か(Newメニュー相当なら普通)`newDocument:`を使ってください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やっぱりそれしかありませんか

Comment: @Чайка さん、[openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:error:のドキュメント](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsdocumentcontroller/1515014-openuntitleddocumentanddisplay?language=objc)を見れば、内部でどんな処理が行われているかが書かれています。それを順番にたどれば、同じ処理ができますよ。